# How to use query string in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used segments in codeigniter but now I want to use query string.

What changes will be in config file and how to use it.

Can i use both segment and query string pattern ?

Comment: what type of query string do you want to pass?

Comment: like http://localhost/test/index?id=345&url=example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```